# Download OS X Yosemite in sections

Tags: macos

Is it possible to download OS X Yosemite in several sections as my internet access is not permanent and OS X Yosemite size is more than 5GB? I need to download it in more than 13 sections.

Comment: What is magical with the 13 segments ?

Answer (score 1):

While downloading OS X Yosemite the connection will drop, it should continue where it left off until sleep mode (I think). In my case, the connection dropped after downloading 2 GB of installer and after restarting, it continued from 2 GB (where it left off).

Answer (score 0):

While the download can be paused from within the App Store nonetheless I personally wouldn't do it, certainly not 13 times, as I've seen it have to start all over sometimes but not all the time. I'd suggest you download it from a location that wouldn't require pausing it.  As an example, I've done it at the Apple store or at a friends that has a much faster connection then I have where it would only take 20 minutes or so.